# How to serialize a custom EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, xml-serialization

Good morning,

I got a class DirObserver with a custom event:

```
public EventHandler<FileDetectedEventArgs> NewFileDetected;
```

I try to serialize this class in a other class with:

```
private XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DirObserver>));
```

But i get an exception:  *FileDetectedEventArgs cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.*

But the FileDetectedEventArgs-Class have a parameterless constructor:

```
public class FileDetectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String Source { get; set; }
    public String Destination { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }

    public FileDetectedEventArgs(String source, String destination, String fullName)
    {
        this.Source = source;
        this.Destination = destination;
        this.FullName = fullName;
    }

    public FileDetectedEventArgs() { }
}
```

Nevertheless the exception will be raised. Whats the problem here?

Thanks and greets
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public EventHandler<FileDetectedEventArgs> NewFileDetected;
```

to

```
public event EventHandler<FileDetectedEventArgs> NewFileDetected;
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventhandlers are not made to be serialized. If you look into the inner exceptions of your exception, you will see it is the EventHandler class which does not have a parameterless constructor; it is a delegate.

You probably want to exclude the eventhandler from serialization; add an XmlIgnore attribute.

Update

I missed the missing *event* keyword as mentioned by @Reniuz. Serialization works with that correction. Still, serializing eventhandlers in general is a bad idea I think.

Comment: i need to serialize the class to xml. The [XmlIgnore] annotation for the event solves the problem